# Maven + Spring Boot: Found multiple occurrences of org.json.JSONObject on the class path:

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, build-dependencies

When I run `mvn test` I get this warning. How can I fix it?

```
Found multiple occurrences of org.json.JSONObject on the class path:

        jar:file:/C:/Users/Chloe/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar!/org/json/JSONObject.class
        jar:file:/C:/Users/Chloe/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar!/org/json/JSONObject.class

You may wish to exclude one of them to ensure predictable runtime behavior
```

Here is my [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/a3f3c85c09c0f70e1c698b8b00c6a42c). The only reference to JSON is

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Apache Maven 3.5.3

Comment: You may want to drop your dependency to `org.json` because it is considered as non-free software. [Spring Boot removed their dependency to it because of this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5929) but this sometimes results in conflicts like yours.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Add under

```
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
```

The following exclusion:

```
 <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Similarly, for Gradle projects:

```
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
}
```

Comment: Has this issue been reported to the Spring Boot project? I can find [a similar ticket for Spring Cloud](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/142) but nothing for Spring Boot. It seems strange that they (transitively) depend on a library that repackages `org.json:json`.

Comment: @DidierL related https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15967 resolved as *don't want to make any changes to the starter.*

Comment: Thanks! I dived a bit more into it and in fact it goes much deeper than that. In fact [Spring Boot removed dependencies to `org.json`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5929) because [it is considered as a non-free license due to the "not evil usage" clause](https://wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/jsonevil). This is also causing [some trouble with the module path](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/issues/116) apparently.

Comment: Classpath clashes even when using spring-boot-starter.. how unfortunate!

Comment: This worked for me on Spring Boot 2.6.3 with Gradle 7.3.3, but I had to delete the cached file for the warning to go away.

Answer (score 37):

**Background**:
`org.json` works great, but has a license clause that some people don't like ("The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil."). So Vaadin wanted to use the library, but couldn't be sure they wouldn't use it for evil someday. Instead, they re-implemented the interface, published `android-json` and used it as a drop in replacement for `org.json`. Others began to use `android-json` as well so that they too would not be bound by the requirement of not using their software for evil.

This is a fine solution, except that when the two libraries are on the classpath, they collide.

**Solution:**
If you get this error from conflicting transitive dependencies, then your best bet is to exclude either Vaadin's `android-json` library (brought in by Spring), or exclude the `org.json` library (brought in by another dependency). Vaadin's version is meant to be an identical implementation, but there are subtle differences.

If you're using `org.json` in your code and it is conflicting with Spring's Vaadin dependency, then I would recommend trying `open-json`. It's a port of Vaadin's re-implementation of `org.json`, but they changed the packages so you won't have any conflicts with `org.json:json` or `com.vaadin.external.google:android-json`

https://github.com/openjson/openjson

Add gradle dependency:

```
    implementation('com.github.openjson:openjson:1.0.12')
```

Or in Maven:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.openjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then update any imports that were being used by `org.json` classes.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have removed my error. 1 down, 99 to go.

Answer (score 4):

Add the below line for gradle projects.

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
configurations {
     testImplementation.exclude group: 'com.vaadin.external.google', module: 'android-json'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Gradle kotlin DSL version based on the accepted answer

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude (
                group = "com.vaadin.external.google",
                module = "android-json"
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude `android-json` module from `testImplementation`.

```
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {

         exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
    
}
```

Comment: Gradle answer on a Maven question.

Comment: @martijnp exclusion strategy between maven and gradle are - in principal, the same.