# Jacoco never called on "mvn install". When triggered manually ("mvn jacoco:report"), says execution data file is missing

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

## Problem

I can't get Jacoco to run properly (`jacoco.exec` is never created):

1. On `mvn install`, only `surefire` is called. The `jacoco` plugin is never even called (it appears nowhere in the logs).
2. On `mvn jacoco:report`, then I get `[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.`.

All of the solutions I've looked at either talk about:

1. how `surefire` would override the `argLine` argument of Jacoco but I'm not using any argLine in my `pom`.
2. the `prepare-agent` goal would is lacking (but I have it).

---

## `pom.xml`

Here is my complete `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bob.blob</groupId>
    <artifactId>blah</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Blah</name>
    <description>Blabla</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version> <!-- For SpringBoot : sets `maven.compiler` properties -->
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.5.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>1.3.2</junit-platform-surefire-provider.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.5</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <bullhorn-sdk-rest.version>1.2.48</bullhorn-sdk-rest.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for the proper config of Redis. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- todo: remove duplicated JSONObject.class ?
                see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980523/9768291 -->
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bullhorn Rest SDK Java : https://github.com/bullhorn/sdk-rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bullhorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${bullhorn-sdk-rest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency used in Bullhorn Rest SDK, removed in Java 11.
        Solution from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47412779/9768291 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Surefire: used for unit tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!-- todo: remove this deprecated dependency?
                        see: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.5.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-platform-surefire-provider.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Jacoco: Test coverage reports (for SonarQube) -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Trying to get the report to be created on simple unit tests too. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-unit-test-report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Overwrite unit test results once the integration tests are done. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-integration-test-report</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

## Debug mode

Here is the result of typing `mvn jacoco:report -debug` :

```
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T11:06:16-04:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\bob\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..
Java version: 12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Users\bob\jdk-12
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Users\bob\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\bob\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Users\bob\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\bob\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.bob.blob:blah:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.2.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.2.2.RELEASE: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix jacoco from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix jacoco to org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin from POM com.bob.blob:blah:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.bob.blob:blah:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [jacoco:report]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.bob.blob:blah >------------------
[INFO] Building Blah 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix jacoco from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix jacoco to org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin from POM com.bob.blob:blah:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sou
rces, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, in
tegration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.bob.blob:blah:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <dataFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec">${jacoco.dataFile}</dataFile>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco"/>
  <outputEncoding default-value="UTF-8">${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</outputEncoding>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <skip default-value="false">${jacoco.skip}</skip>
  <sourceEncoding default-value="UTF-8">${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
  <title default-value="${project.name}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report (default-cli) @ blah ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1757500, ConflictMarker.markTime=465700, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=185, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=842400
, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=511300, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=63, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=9004400, ConflictResolver
.conflictItemCount=154, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=610516900, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=14868300}
[DEBUG] org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.5
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-alpha-6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.10:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.10:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.10:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]             commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.2:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]       commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]          oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]          xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.8.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:jar:0.8.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]          org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]       org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.2:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]    org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:jar:0.8.5:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.22
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:1.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:4.8.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: oro:oro:jar:2.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.8.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:jar:0.8.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:jar:0.8.5
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5, parent: jdk.internal.loade
r.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4e0e2f2a]
[DEBUG] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: site.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.SiteResourceLoader'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: runtime.log.invalid.references => 'false'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath,site'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global => 'true'.
[DEBUG] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[DEBUG] *******************************************************************
[DEBUG] Starting Apache Velocity v1.5 (compiled: 2007-02-22 08:52:29)
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance initializing.
[DEBUG] Default Properties File: org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties
[DEBUG] LogSystem has been deprecated. Please use a LogChute implementation.
[DEBUG] Default ResourceManager initializing. (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl)
[DEBUG] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader
[DEBUG] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.SiteResourceLoader
[DEBUG] ResourceCache: initialized (class org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl)
[DEBUG] Default ResourceManager initialization complete.
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Literal
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Macro
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Parse
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Include
[DEBUG] Loaded System Directive: org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach
[DEBUG] Created '20' parsers.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : initialization starting.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = true : VMs defined inline may replace previous VM definitions
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : autoload off : VM system will not automatically reload global library macros
[DEBUG] Velocimacro : Velocimacro : initialization complete.
[DEBUG] RuntimeInstance successfully initialized.
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:report' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) dataFile = C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\target\jacoco.exec
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\target\site\jacoco
[DEBUG]   (f) outputEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.bob.blob:blah:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) title = Blah
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.256 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-16T15:05:58-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

## Normal command

When running `mvn install` :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.bob.blob:blah >------------------
[INFO] Building Blah 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ blah ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ blah ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ blah ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ blah ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ blah ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

// ... SKIPPING ALL OF THE SPRINGBOOT STUFF

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 27.772 s - in com.bob.blob.blah.BlahApplicationTests
[INFO] Running com.bob.blob.blah.RandomTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in com.bob.blob.blah.RandomTest
2019-12-16 15:11:10.717  INFO 14224 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.3:war (default-war) @ blah ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [blah] in [C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\target\ROOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [621 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\target\ROOT.war
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ blah ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\target\ROOT.war to C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\bob\blob\blah\0.0.1-
SNAPSHOT\blah-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\bob\Documents\Github\blah-on-codecommit\pom.xml to C:\Users\bob\.m2\repository\com\bob\blob\blah\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\blah-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  35.674 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-16T15:11:13-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

## Eventually

We will add `failsafe` as a plugin too, in the future, but that's not yet done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found an answer that helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36305148/9768291

Basically, I was trying to set up the jacoco plugin within the `pluginManagement` tag, but it hadn't been declared as a plugin in the first place. I moved my code from `build/pluginManagement/plugins` to `build/plugins` and now it all works properly.